# SQL stored function to concatenate name and date

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I am trying to code a stored function which accepts date (2020-09-04) and name, then return a string like a Name birthday is Sep 04, 2020. I started with the below and finding the issue.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION concatenate(X CHAR(24),Y date date))
Returns CHAR(50)
BEGIN
declare month char(20);
SELECT month(date, %m) into month;
Return concat(X, 'Birthday is', ' ', month);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Review date functions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: MySql doesn't use T-SQL. Only Sybase and MS SQL Server use T-SQL.

Comment: I edited to replace the term UDF with stored function, because you aren't writing an UDF. [UDF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/5.7/en/adding-udf.html) is MySQL's term for code you would write in C or C++ and compile it as an extension to the MySQL Server. You're writing a [stored function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your script:

- There is one bracket and data type to much on the first line (second parameter).
- You are using a [reserved name / keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) (`month`) as variable name without quoting.
- [`MONTH` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) doesn't support two parameters.
- Not a issue but a recommendation: Use proper variable names (not just `X` and `Y`).

You can use this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION concatenate(name CHAR(24), birthday DATE)
RETURNS CHAR(50)
BEGIN
  RETURN CONCAT_WS(' ', name, 'Birthday is', DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%b %d, %Y'));
END
```

You can use the function like this:

```
-- simple example
SELECT concatenate('Tim', now()); -- Tim Birthday is Sep 04, 2020

-- or
SELECT concatenate(name, birthday)
FROM table_name
```

But you can also use the logic directly on a `SELECT` statement without using a UDF:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', name, 'Birthday is', DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%b %d, %Y'))
FROM table_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31d2cbe6843715f29eb07174a6ca9964)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Fformat the date lie you want it, for that you must use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) like PSalmon suggested.

[Reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) like MONTH should not be used, that will cause an error as noticed but for your purpose it is simpler to use an user defined variable like @month

Use

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION concatenate(X CHAR(24),Y date )
Returns CHAR(50)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare _month char(20);
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Y, '%b %d, %Y') INTO _month;
Return concat(X, "'s Birthday is ", _month);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

RESUlt

```
# concatenate('temp','2020-01-01')
temp's Birthday is Jan 01, 2020
```

Or you use

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION concatenate(X CHAR(24),Y date )
Returns CHAR(50)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Y, '%b %d, %Y') INTO @month;
Return concat(X, "'s Birthday is ", @month);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```